# Redux persist how to persist ONLY when I click on button

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I want to know if its possible to persist my Store ONLY when I decide it, for example only when I click on a Persist Button, because I'm using huge data and serialisation cause a navigator issue OUT OF MEMORY
Have you any idea ?